# Where in the Vedas does it declare as “Agnisomatmakam Jagat”?

Tags: vedas, agni, soma

I know “Agnisomatmakam jagat” is mentioned in Mahabharata and in a few Upanishads and other texts but where in the Vedas is this principle declared. Which Veda? Which verse and which hymn?